# Make a local R leaflet html map connect to a dynamic online dataset

Tags: html, r, github, shiny, leaflet

I'm working on a leaflet map in R. The coordinates presenting in this map is saved in a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rrEJiuxr4nafTqUQBlPpUdGwvGeGtBJExlPJdday2uw/pub?gid=353641802&single=true&output=csv) and I'm using `read.csv` to import the data into R.

Here is my sample code below:

```
geolocation <- read.csv(url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rrEJiuxr4nafTqUQBlPpUdGwvGeGtBJExlPJdday2uw/pub?gid=353641802&single=true&output=csv"),
                    header = T,
                    stringsAsFactors = F)

test <- leaflet() %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          fitBounds(max(geolocation$lng)+0.4, 
                    max(geolocation$lat)+0.4, 
                    min(geolocation$lng)-0.4, 
                    min(geolocation$lat)-0.4) %>%
          addMarkers(lng = geolocation$lng, 
                     lat = geolocation$lat, 
                     popup = geolocation$ID)
saveWidget(test, "test.html",selfcontained = T)
```

My objective is embed this html in a webpage, but also when the coordinates in the google sheet are updated, the markers in this embedded html can be changed as well (at least upon refreshing the webpage).

However using my current script this scope certainly cannot happen, because the coordinates are hard coded in the local **test.html** file.

There is one other option I can think of but I don't want to use is creating a shiny app and host the app in shinyapp.io, then use `<iframe>` to embed the app in a webpage. I only have an account for myself which is free and only have 25 hours allowance per month and I don't think the office would like to create a paid account to support this little project.

So is there some other way that I can host this map so it is able to read dynamic data source (when data source changed, the result on the map will change upon refresh)? I was also told github can handle this kind of problem but I have been trying without success.

Appreciate for your ideas.

Comment: You don't really need R for this app, just use JS and save your sheet in json, but if you really want to use R you will need a server that can run R

Comment: @HubertL Thanks for your comment, but I don't really know much about JS let alone writing JS from scratch.

Comment: Then I think going for free shinyapps.io is enough to start using your app (25hr/month is about 1hr per day and you can have  more than one account) and convince your boss to pay 100$/y ...